# Activable or Activatable?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, suffixes

A guy suggested changing my word from "activable" to "activatable". Chrome's spell checker also suggests that. However, I can see *activable* in most dictionaries ([1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/activable), [2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activable), [3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/activable)) while I don't see *activatable* in these (except Wiktionary).

Which one do you usually use?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=activable%2Cactivatable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cactivable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cactivatable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DatVM Most adjectives ending in "-ible" and "-able" stem from verbs. "active" is not a verb, while "activate" is.

Comment: Context may help, especially if you would be interested in an alternative synonym. In a technical context (e.g. computing) the commonly-used form may differ from that in general contexts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I don't normally use either. If I had to form the word on the fly, I would probably use *activatable.* But *activable* does fit the pattern used for some other verbs.

The suffix *-able* usually attaches to the bare form of a verb (sometimes with spelling changes, like doubling the last consonant letter or dropping a "silent e"). But for some verbs derived from Latin, the corresponding *-able* adjective is constructed on a different stem.

As a general class, *-ate* verbs are derived from Latin, and many of them have corresponding *-able* adjectives without the *-te*: *separate* and *separable, estimate* and *estimable, replicate* and *replicable.*

The specific verb *activate* seems to not actually be derived from a single Classical Latin word: the Oxford English Dictionary says *activate* was formed in English from the adjective *active* and the verb suffix *-ate.* (However, the entry does mention  a "post-classical Latin *activare* (13th cent. in a British source)").

But if we treat the *replicate/replicable* pattern as a general rule that can be considered productive for any Latinate *-ate* verb, regardless of the details of its etymology, then it is valid to form *activable* from *activate.*

I would say that any simple rule about the use of *-atable* vs. *-able* will probably only describe one possible pattern of usage; the actual usage is kind of messy. With that caveat, here is the advice given in H.W. Fowler's *Dictionary of Modern English Usage* (first published 1926; re-published 2009):

> Verbs with the Latin-derived ending *-ate* that have established adjectives drop the *-ate* (*demonstrable, abominable, alienable, appreciable, calculable, expiable, execrable,* &c.); & nonce-adjectives from such verbs should be similarly formed (*accumulable, adulterable, educable, confiscable, saturable,* &c.) except when the verb is disyllabic (*dictatable, creatable, castratable, crematable, locatable;* not *dictable* &c.

(*able*, 1, p. 2)

On the other hand, the Google Ngram Viewer (mentioned in a comment) shows a preference for *activatable*:

[image]